# How can i make a php script which will automatically generate links of my folder's file

Tags: php

I want to make a script for my website which will automatically generate links,
i will put all my files in a folder and i want those files will show in a web page and can be downloadable.
please help...

Comment: You need to ask a question about a specific problem which can be replicated see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Perhaps Apache's [Directory Listing](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) would suffice?

Comment: if , php you will have to use a database, that on load will call your page form the folder dynamically

Comment: @dean there is absolutely **no** requirement for a database in this case, as several answers show. It can be discussed whether they are "good", but they suffice the given requirements without the need for a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GLOB()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to create an array for all the files from directory in alphabetical order then echo them out with a foreach() loop:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'download/';
    $files = GLOB($folder . '*{.*}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'" download>'.basename($file).'</a>';
    }
?>
```

If you just want to list files with specific extensions:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'download/';
    $file_types = array(
        'doc',
        'pdf',
        'txt'
    );

    $files = GLOB($folder . '*{.' . implode(',.',$file_types) . '}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'" download>'.basename($file).'</a>';
    }
?>
```

To put them in an unordered-list:

```
    $files = GLOB($folder . '*{.' . implode(',.',$file_types) . '}', GLOB_BRACE);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" download>'.basename($file).'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '<ul>';
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<h2>Download Folder Listing</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="file1.txt" download>file1.txt</a></li>
  <li><a href="file2.txt" download>file2.txt</a></li>
  <li><a href="file3.txt" download>file3.txt</a></li>
  <li><a href="file4.txt" download>file4.txt</a></li>
  <li><a href="file5.txt" download>file5.txt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it's working but how to make the links show under a stylish table ?

Comment: Your "stylish table" is too broad. I would suggest you to use unordered-list-list and search "how to style unordered-list with css". I will edit the answer to put them in ul li.

Comment: you just solve my problem man..... thanks and love you bro

Comment: run the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you really want.

But if it's just for your usage :

Install an apache server

put all your files in a folder inside apache

Don't put any index.html inside this folder

go to http://localhost/nameOfYourFolder

We can't help you more, if you don't try something and ask a real question